# Not allow multi select CheckBoxSelectColumn in Obout grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, obout

I am using OBOUT grid and added `CheckBoxSelectColumn` column. I would like not allow user to select multiple checkboxes. i.e only allowed single select checkbox in the grid.

**How to do iterate grid and deselect allow and select only sender?.**

I wrote client script method

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function Grid1_Select(sender, args) {
        alert('Its coming here')
           ///need to write code here
    }
</script>

  <obout:Grid ID="mGrid" runat="server" >
     <ClientSideEvents OnClientSelect="Grid1_Select" 
         ExposeSender="true" />                

     <Columns>
         <obout:CheckBoxSelectColumn ShowHeaderCheckBox="false" ControlType="Standard" HeaderText="Select"  runat="server"   >

         </obout:CheckBoxSelectColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, you have to write the code on rowcommand event, in this, first you will select your selected checkbox and disable the others one. Or you check,if any checkbox is already checked then dont check new one.

In simple, you have to work on rowcommand.

Answer (score 0):

You Need to Set

```
ShowHeaderCheckBox="true"
```

:)